# How to set default secondary screen position to top

Tags: display

I often plug my macbook to a secondary screen, but *different* ones. Every time I change the secondary screen, the macbook considers it as a secondary display (*this is ok*) but on the **right** of my main display. I would like it to be on **top** by default, without having to go to **System Preferences** -> **Display** and then dragging the secondary display.

Is there a way to change a settings so every time I plug a new display, it is placed on **top** of my main display?

[image]
*What happens by default*

[image]
*What I want by default*

Comment: In system prefs you can tick the box to have the display icon in the menu bar - quick access...

Answer (score 1):

There's no setting to set a default layout on monitor connection.

But I've created a simple utility to do that vertical layout faster: [VerticalMonitorLayout.swift](https://github.com/alin23/mac-utils/blob/main/VerticalMonitorLayout.swift)

#### Installation

Launch Terminal.app and run the following commands inside it:

```sh
curl https://github.com/alin23/mac-utils/raw/main/bin/VerticalMonitorLayout -o ~/Desktop/VerticalMonitorLayout
chmod +x ~/Desktop/VerticalMonitorLayout
```

You should now see a file called **VerticalMonitorLayout** on your Desktop.
If you double click the file, it will open a Terminal window and arrange your external monitor above your MacBook display.

You can safely press <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> inside the Terminal window to close it after that, the utility is one off and does not need to keep running.